# SSD1306 / U8glib display fonts and commands

Tags: library, display, u8glib, command-line

I cannot seem to find any reference for the SSD 1306 or U8glib display font library or any command reference, like all the options for display() etc. For my fonts I been going into the utility folder and scrolling through notepad for the U8glib library but its very croweded with numbers and code. is there any reference for both libraries online that is user friendly?

Answer (score 2):

First, [u8glib](https://github.com/olikraus/u8glib) is superceded by [u8g2](https://github.com/olikraus/u8g2/wiki)

Second, the [u8glib wiki](https://github.com/olikraus/u8glib/wiki) has a command reference and font reference.

As does the [u8g2 wiki](https://github.com/olikraus/u8g2/wiki).

Neither reference lists a `display()` command.

Comment: OK GREAT iLL CHECK IT OUT

Comment: lots of good info on there, thanks. So I added some font and sometimes I get many symbols (I have a scroll set up) How do you grab just one of those symbols, for example, an arrow?

Comment: If you have a different question, post it as a new question.

Comment: there is not much variety of fonts available

Comment: What are you actually looking to do? There are many fonts and even non-English character set fonts.

Comment: display is in the SSD1306 library, is there a wiki for that?

Comment: Im just toggling through some functions and have a display to show what mode im in but the default font kind of sucks. Looking for something more creative.

Comment: https://github.com/olikraus/u8g2/wiki/fntlistall hundreds

Comment: u8g2 handles SSD1306 communication, so you should not need a separate library...

Comment: ok Ill have to load the U8g2 into my library

Comment: what about icons, like battery indicators, meters, etc. is there librarys with ready made images, or bitmap images?

Comment: I wonder if you are even reading or looking at the font lists available on the links. https://github.com/olikraus/u8g2/wiki/fntgrpsiji

Comment: yeah I read through all of them, look about the same, adobe old standard etc

Comment: trying this one now u8g_font_helvB14, seems to be about the best one

Comment: so in that github library you have provided with the siji text, how do I grab one of those icons? I dont need them all

Comment: You set the font using something like `u8g2.setFont(u8g2_font_siji_t);`. Looking at the font diagram, some battery icons start at character position `0xe242` through `0xe24b`. You may need to enable UTF8 support with `u8g2.enableUTF8Print();`. Then, you print a string with the 2-byte 'character', like `u8g2.print("\0xe2\0x42");` Note, I haven't tested this myself, but I read the documentation.

Comment: Ok I see, I will try it out